# What conditions are needed for Onsager reciprocal relations?

Tags: statistical-mechanics, solid-state-physics, non-equilibrium

I often find a thorough discussion of the conditions that must hold for a theorem lacking, especially in the sense of what they actually mean physically.

Could anyone write up what kind of systems when will follow the onsager reciprocal relations? And what does this mean for the kind of physical system that falls in these parameters, so what are we really talking about?